# Duplicating items on listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a program that records homework in a list box, and sorts it by the date it is due. However, when I try to sort the data by date, it does so, but duplicates each item in the list box. This can be rectified by closing the program and opening it again, but this is very inconvenient. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the code for the two

frmSplashScreen:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmSplashscreen
Dim dates() As Date = {}
Dim temparray() As String = {}
Dim temparray2() As String = {}
Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath
Dim newuser As Boolean = False
Dim sorted As Boolean = False
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnAdd.Click
    If lstDate.Items.Contains("No assignments yet!") Then
        lstDate.Items.Clear()
    End If
    frmAdd.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Me_mouseenter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
    If sorted = False And lstDate.Items.Contains("No assignments yet!") = False Then
        SortByDate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmSplashscreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If File.Exists(Path & "Assignments.crw") = False Then
        newuser = True
        lstDate.Items.Add("No assignments yet!")
    Else
        FileOpen(1, Path & "Assignments.crw", OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1)
            Dim output As String = LineInput(1)
            lstAssignments.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "-") + 1, InStr(output, "_") - (InStr(output, "-") + 1)))
            lstAN.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "_") + 1, output.Length))
            lstDate.Items.Add(Mid(output, 1, InStr(output, "-") - 1))
            Array.Resize(temparray, temparray.Length + 1)
            temparray(temparray.Length - 1) = output
        End While
    End If
    FileClose(1)
    If lstDate.Items.Contains("No assignments yet!") = False Then
        SortByDate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortByDate()

    For Each x In lstDate.Items
        MsgBox(x)
        Array.Resize(dates, dates.Length + 1)
        dates(dates.Length - 1) = x
    Next

    Array.Sort(dates)
    ' Sort dates.
    temparray2 = {}
    ' Empty temparray2 for resizing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    ' Declare counter
    For Each x In dates
        ' Looping through dates...
        Dim result As Integer
        ' ...Declare result.
        For Each y In temparray
            ' Nestled for loop to check each result against one another. This time looping through temparray.
            result = InStr(y, x)
            ' Search for x (The date) in y (the line of the file)
            If result <> 0 Then
                ' If it is found...
                Array.Resize(temparray2, temparray2.Length + 1)
                counter = counter + 1
                temparray2(counter - 1) = y
                ' Add y to the array temparray2 in chronological order.
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Dim num As Integer = 0
    ' Declare num
    lstAN.Items.Clear()
    lstAssignments.Items.Clear()
    lstDate.Items.Clear()
    temparray = {}
    lstAN.Items.Clear()
    lstAssignments.Items.Clear()
    lstDate.Items.Clear()
    For Each x In temparray2
        Array.Resize(temparray, temparray2.Length)
        temparray(num) = x
        lstAssignments.Items.Add(Mid(x, InStr(x, "-") + 1, InStr(x, "_") - (InStr(x, "-") + 1)))
        lstAN.Items.Add(Mid(x, InStr(x, "_") + 1, x.Length))
        lstDate.Items.Add(Mid(x, 1, InStr(x, "-") - 1))
        num += 1
    Next
    ' Loop through temparray2 making temparray the exact same and adding the array to the listbox.
    sorted = True
End Sub

Private Sub SortMyLife()
    If File.Exists(Path & "Assignments.crw") = False Then
        newuser = True
        lstDate.Items.Add("No assignments yet!")
    Else
        FileOpen(1, Path & "Assignments.crw", OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1)
            Dim output As String = LineInput(1)
            lstAssignments.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "-") + 1, InStr(output, "_") - (InStr(output, "-") + 1)))
            lstAN.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "_") + 1, output.Length))
            lstDate.Items.Add(Mid(output, 1, InStr(output, "-") - 1))
            Array.Resize(temparray, temparray.Length + 1)
            temparray(temparray.Length - 1) = output
        End While
    End If
    FileClose(1)
    If lstDate.Items.Contains("No assignments yet!") = False Then
        SortByDate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Call SortMyLife()
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

frmAdd (for adding a new assignment)

```
Public Class frmAdd
Dim temparray() As String = {}
Dim temparray2() As String = {}
Dim dates() As Date = {}
Dim sorted As Boolean

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim datedue As Date = dtpDue.Text
    Dim Subject As String = cbxSbjct.Text
    Dim Additional As String = rtfAN.Text
    Dim Path As String = Application.StartupPath & "Assignments.crw"
    If datedue > Now() Then
        If Subject <> "Choose a subject" Then
            FileOpen(1, Path, OpenMode.Append)
            Dim output As String = dtpDue.Text & "-" & Subject & "_" & Additional
            If frmSplashscreen.lstAssignments.Items.Contains("No assignments yet!") Then
                frmSplashscreen.lstAssignments.Items.Clear()
                frmSplashscreen.lstDate.Items.Clear()
                frmSplashscreen.lstAN.Items.Clear()
            End If

            frmSplashscreen.lstAssignments.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "-") + 1, InStr(output, "_") - (InStr(output, "-") + 1)))
            frmSplashscreen.lstAN.Items.Add(Mid(output, InStr(output, "_") + 1, output.Length))
            frmSplashscreen.lstDate.Items.Add(dtpDue.Text)

            PrintLine(1, output)

            FileClose(1)
            For Each x In frmSplashscreen.lstDate.Items
                MsgBox(x)
            Next
            Me.Close()
            frmSplashscreen.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please enter a subject in the box provided")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a date in the future", vbInformation, "Error")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have some **VB6** functions and syntax in your code, **is this VB6 or VB.Net**. If it's **VB.Net** get rid of the old **VB6** functions and syntax and use the newer functions, just a suggestion... Also look at how your handling your array's, that would be a good start.

Comment: As @436f6465786572 mentions, this looks like VB6. You should convert the VB6 to VB.NET.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Which bits are like vb6?

Comment: @Behavior: The VB6 style code includes using FileOpen/PrintLine instead of the classes in the [System.IO Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and Mid/InStr instead of the methods provided by the [System.String Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ how would i do that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something as simple as `ListBoxHoliday.Items.Clear` before the sort happens?

Comment: Yes, in numerous places, but to no success